# running ./configure in asterisk

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, asterisk, configure

currently i am installing asterisk in Ubuntu 14.04 and i am stacked when I run the `./configure` command line. may someone help me please!

here is what the console displays:

```
./configure: line 1: Script: command not found
./configure: line 2: $'\E]0': command not found
./configure: line 2: root@administrator:: command not found
./configure: line 3: config.guess: command not found
./configure: line 4: $'\E]0': command not found
./configure: line 4: root@administrator:: command not found
./configure: line 5: config.guess: command not found
./configure: line 6: $'\E]0': command not found
./configure: line 6: root@administrator:: command not found
./configure: line 7: bash:: command not found
./configure: line 8: $'\E]0': command not found
./configure: line 8: root@administrator:: command not found
./configure: line 9: bash:: command not found
./configure: line 10: $'\E]0': command not found
./configure: line 10: root@administrator:: command not found
./configure: line 11: bash:: command not found
./configure: line 12: $'\E]0': command not found
./configure: line 12: root@administrator:: command not found
./configure: line 13: bash:: command not found
./configure: line 14: $'\E]0': command not found
./configure: line 14: root@administrator:: command not found
./configure: line 15: bash:: command not found
./configure: line 16: $'\E]0': command not found
./configure: line 16: root@administrator:: command not found
./configure: line 17: bash:: command not found
./configure: line 18: $'\E]0': command not found
./configure: line 18: root@administrator:: command not found
./configure: line 19: bash:: command not found
./configure: line 20: $'\E]0': command not found
./configure: line 20: root@administrator:: command not found
./configure: line 21: bash:: command not found
./configure: line 22: $'\E]0': command not found
./configure: line 22: root@administrator:: command not found
./configure: line 23: bash:: command not found
./configure: line 24: $'\E]0': command not found
./configure: line 24: root@administrator:: command not found
./configure: line 24: root@administrator:: command not found
./configure: line 25: $'\r\E[K\E[A\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\E[3Pnano': command not found
./configure: line 25: root@administrator:: command not found
./configure: line 25: root@administrator:: command not found
./configure: line 25: root@administrator:: command not found
./configure: line 26: $'\r\E[K\E[A\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C.sh\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bscript': command not found
./configure: line 26: root@administrator:: command not found
./configure: line 27: $'\r\E[K\E[A\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\E[C\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\E[K\a\a\a\a\a\amake': command not found
./configure: line 28: Makefile:105:: command not found
./configure: line 29: $'****\r': command not found
./configure: line 30: addons: command not found
./configure: line 31: addons: command not found
./configure: line 32: $'****\r': command not found
./configure: line 33: make:: command not found
./configure: line 34: $'\E]0': command not found
./configure: line 34: root@administrator:: command not found
./configure: line 35: bash:: command not found
./configure: line 36: $'\E]0': command not found
./configure: line 36: root@administrator:: command not found
./configure: line 38: Script: command not found
```

Comment: Add the steps you have followed so far.

Comment: Insufficient information. You need to post exactly what you did to make this happen.

Comment: It looks like you edited `configure` script and it's no longer the usual ascii text. When `bash` encounters a command it can't find the message is usually `bash: yourcommand: command not found`. The output of your script is `bash:: command not found`. It is certainly printing a non-printable character in between `::`. The escape sequences `$'\E]0'` is a proof that configure contains escape sequences.

Comment: Looks like your bash shell is not working properly. Also the escaped characters look like come from some kind of terminal coloring program, like grep's --color=always.

Answer (score 1):

Seams like you install colorfull versions of bash utilites (ls,cat,sed,grep etc) and that cause some issues.

There are no way determine what exactly you broken.

For first install from source highly recommended use centos 5 or centos 6 64bit.

On ubuntu you can install asterisk from apt-repo using

```
apt-get install asterisk
```